# How do I get rid of any type of Memory Saver in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, google-workspace, google-developers-console, google-hangouts

Issue: We have applications that require the tab for the webpage app to always to be without any memory saving and active. The ports and instances of the tab must remain 100% active without interruption. We have turned off several items in chrome with no effect and included adding a white listing to chrome to not look at that IT Address schema. What have others found to turnt his off completely?

Comment: The last working version for our app in Chrome is before the memory feature was added by Chrome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.